# Need to write batch file results to a text file

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file that I am running nightly, and I need to have the results written to a results file (doesn't matter what type). Here's my delema.

Here's basically the batch file:

```
SHUTDOWN /r /m \\MACHINE1 /t %1 /c "This machine is forcibly restarting in %1 seconds!" /f
SHUTDOWN /r /m \\MACHINE2 /t %1 /c "This machine is forcibly restarting in %1 seconds!" /f
SHUTDOWN /r /m \\MACHINE3 /t %1 /c "This machine is forcibly restarting in %1 seconds!" /f
```

It contains approx 248 machines that are rebooted nightly. I would like to be able to write the results of which ones responded, and which ones didn't. More importantly, which ones did. Maybe like a `errorlevel==0` and `errorlevel==1` type thing? I don't know if that would apply here.

Also, instead of actually listing `MACHINE1`, `MACHINE2`, etc. how can I get it to read the machine names from a text file?

This will be ran on a desktop machine behind me as a nightly task if that helps.

How would I do this with having so many numerous entries.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

When you run it use `shutdown.bat >> shutdown.log 2>&1` to put the output to a file.

To read the machine names from a file you can use a FOR loop like so:

```
FOR /F %%name IN (machines.txt) DO SHUTDOWN /r /m \\%%name /t %1 /c "This machine is forcibly restarting in %1 seconds!" /f
```

With each machine name on a new line.

A nicely formatted one:

```
@echo off
FOR /F %%name IN (machines.txt) DO (
    echo %%name
    SHUTDOWN /r /m \\%%name /t %1 /c "This machine is forcibly restarting in %1 seconds!" /f
)
```